# Convert polyline to a region

Tags: mapinfo

I am using Mapinfo Pro 8. I have a polyline of a river. I want to create a boundary 20 metres each side of the river and then create a polygon 40 metres in width that mirrors the shape of the river. How can I do this?

PS I also use QGIS but am more familiar with Mapinfo

Comment: Buffer your polyline by 20m https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CtlYCAS

Comment: Why are you using MapInfo 8? Also the buffer tool in qgis will do this readily and you can export as a .tab file. Just set the buffer distance to 20m.

Answer (score -2):

Create the buffer twice one with 20 meter and then 60 meters on the same polyline.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: does that helped @KevanRichards